# How to access columns in table using numbers rather than using names?

Tags: powershell

I have a csv file with large number of columns . I have imported it to a table using the below code:

```
$table = Import-Csv "C:\data.csv"
$row = $table.Item(0);
$row.'Title'
```

I want to access the column using number . I want to do something like this :

```
$row[0]
```

How do I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this, maybe?

```
$table = import-csv "C:\data.csv"
$cols = $table[0].psobject.properties.name

$table.$($cols[0])
```

Comment: This Worked . Thanks a lot . I modified it like this :     $cols = $table[0].psobject.properties.name
$colName = $cols[0];
$colName
$table[0].$colName

Answer (score 0):

This should work for CSV:

```
$table[0]
$table[0].Title
```

> I want to access the column using number . I want to use a for loop.

This is for rows, for the columns, see **mjolinor**'s answer.

```
$table = Import-Csv Import-Csv 'C:\data.csv'

for($i=0; $i -lt $table.Count ; $i++){
    $table[$i].Title
}
```

Comment: I want to access the column using number . I want to use a for loop . This wont work.